# -webkit-box-reflect and position:absolute

Tags: webkit, css

I have the following HTML code snippet running on Chrome Canary build

```
<div id="debug" class="debug" >TEST</div>
```

Also, I have the following CSS code snippet

```
-webkit-box-reflect: below 0px
                     -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                     from(transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)));
```

It works as expected. It shows the reflection of the word **TEST**.

But the reflection does **not** work when I have add the `position:absolute` as the following:

```
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px
                     -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                     from(transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)));
```

What do I need to make it the -webkit-box-reflect work with position:absolute?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It does work on the standard version of Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/eqBqt/ you might want to try adding a parent and applying position absolute to that.

Answer (score 0):

Make a div around the div/tag you're using for "test".And make that one absolute.